# How to use localStorage from an imported library?

Tags: local-storage, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I am trying out Svelte (coming from a Vue3/Quasar background) and I have a hard time using `localStorage` from within an exported helper function.

If I have the following code in `src/libs.js`

```js
export const callZinc = () => {
  console.log(`hello ${localStorage.getItem("login")`)
}
```

the compilation fails with

```
localStorage is not defined
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at Module.callZinc (/src/libs.js:4:53)
    at Main.svelte:5:2
(...)
```

I found out that `localStorage` must be called in `.svelte` files in the `onMount()` hook, but how to use it in an exported function?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on when and were the function is to be used. You can also use `onMount` outside of Svelte files, but of course the code will then be executed in a delayed fashion.

The main problem is probably that you call the function from a component's top level scope. As long as you call the function from within `onMount` in the component, it will work. When using server side rendering (the default in Svelte Kit), you cannot rely on browser APIs to be available at component creation because that happens on the server.

---

In the given example, `callZinc` is a function, so there is no immediate access to `localStorage`; if this is not the case and the library uses it at the top level, you may have to do something like using a dynamic import to make sure the execution does not happen on the server just from the import.

```js
onMount(async () => {
    const libraryModule = await import('...');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to force client-side only mode, so that the browser-only elements are always available?

Comment: See e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1650), it shows a configuration that disables prerendering and SSR. (This is not really recommended. Initial page load can be faster with SSR.)

Comment: (The documentation of the configuration is [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration), but it seem incomplete...)

Comment: I saw the discussions you pointed at but I thought that I was missing something. It is surprising that it is such a difficult task to build an SPA.